# Steps to import a parachain running in a production environment to test environment?

Tags: testing, migration

I am using export-state to copy a parachain running in production environment to development with all the configuration and blocks data. I am following these steps. Can any one please review the steps, if I am missing any thing. Since when I run the parachain in development, it does not produce blocks:

1. I executed a command similar to the following in against production parachain node to generate its chain specs with the current state:

`./target/release/my-node export-state --chain=raw-parachain-chainspec.json --base-path /tmp/para/ali > new_chainspc.json`

2. Generate genesis state file:

`./target/release/my-node export-genesis-state --chain=new_chainspc.json > new-genesis`

3. Generate wasm:

`./target/release/my-node export-genesis-wasm --chain=new_chainspc.json > new_wasm`

4. I spin two nodes of polkadot relaychian using follwoing commands in my development envirnoment:

```
./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/ali \
--chain ~/polkadot/polkadot/tmp/raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30333 --ws-port 9944 \
--unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors=all

./target/release/polkadot \
--bob \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/bob \
--chain ~/polkadot/polkadot/tmp/raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30334 --ws-port 9945 \
--unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors=all
```

5. I run my parachain collator using the following command:

```
./target/release/my-node \
--collator \
--chain new_chainspc.json \
--port 40333 --ws-port 8844 --rpc-port 8833 \
--base-path /tmp/para/ali \
--unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external \
--rpc-cors=all --rpc-methods=Unsafe \
--node-key 7a9c984f2254f80eb54e09ab9f37b41261b1cf6ba230cff6ff7982e78e4584b6 \
-- \
--execution wasm \
--chain raw-local-chainspec.json \
--port 30343 --ws-port 9977 \
--unsafe-rpc-external --unsafe-ws-external \
--rpc-cors=all
```

6. Registered parachain with relay chain using new_genesis and new_wasm generated above.

After performing all these steps, the relaychain start producing blocks but no parachain blocks are produced. Am I missing some important piece of info?

Comment: Have you tried using [chopsticks](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks)? Easy tool to import live chain state for testing purposes.

Comment: Hey @Bruno, Thank you for the response. 

Let me check the tool that you mentioned too. But I am also interested to know if I am doing any thing wrong. Can you please just have a look on my steps and give me feedback, if I am doiing it correctly.

Comment: I wrote a tutorial a while ago: https://hackmd.io/3BAy3HEzRVO2sBFnUaBVKA. But checking your steps I can not see any problem of the way you are doing it. Any errors that can help to debug or just not producing block?

Comment: Let me run it again and past my log here

Comment: I think we can post any thing in teh comments. The parachian does not show any error message please

Comment: I figure out one error and that is about the collators keys. What I noticed that the collator keys generated by export-state are not what I have set. What is my guess so far, export-state changes the collator keys  (for security reasons, may be). How can I set my collator keys again to my custom keys?

Comment: You found your solution?

Comment: No I did not find any solution yet? @Daan